# Javascript does no capturing?

Tags: javascript

Is it right, that javascript does NO capturing?

Following example:

```
var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

var nameByIndex = function (n){
  return names[n];
}; //in C++ now names would be captured f.e. "by value"

console.log(nameByIndex(1));
names = undefined; //with C++ capturing by value, this would have no "side-effect"
console.log(nameByIndex(1));
```

Now as far as I can see the function does NOT `capture` the names.

EDIT: Capturing does only happen if I pass `names` by value via an IIFE, right? 
example:

```
var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

var nameByIndex = (function(names) {
    var _names = names;
    return function (n){
        return _names[n];
    };
})(names);

console.log(nameByIndex(1)); // outputs one
names = undefined; 
console.log(nameByIndex(2)); // outputs two
```

SOLUTION: OK now I got it, if its passed by value via IIFE, the returned closure does a function local lookup und finds the "passed by value" names. Without IIFE, it looks like a reference capture, but its only a lookup in the outer scope when the function is executed.

Comment: what is the log ? how is the second different from first ?

Comment: @meagar Stupid technicalities. The function has access to a variable from an outer scope, so even if it technically wasn't a closure (which I really doubt, that's a rather strange definition of closure) it's still perfectly clear what is meant.

Comment: @meagar The code in the question might as well be part of another function (and in that case, the `var` in front of the definition of `names` would make it a local). And no matter what exactly OP finds confusing about the behavior here, it'll behave the same way when whether it's at global scope or in another function.

Comment: @meagar Are you saying this affects the behavior, or at least the explanation for the behavior? (Whatever behavior that may be specifically.) I don't see anything in the code depending on whether `names` is global or a closed-over local.

Comment: OK I see that its not a closure here. I edit my question.

Comment: @meagar Could you elaborate how exactly the behavior differs? I would expect the exact same output from OP's code when put into a function and when put at global scope. Running both variants on jsfiddle.net indeed gives the same output. Give me something **tangible** please.

Comment: @cakl Well, no, there is a closure here, but both inner and outer scopes refer to the same variable; it's in-scope both places, so it isn't a *useful* closure.

Comment: @delnan I'm not talking about it behaving differently; I'm talking about needing to provide `namesByIndex` with a *different* variable that the one shared by both scopes, so that setting the shared variable to a new value doesn't affect the copy needed by `namesByIndex`. This would do it: `var namesByIndex = (function(names) { return function(i) { return names[i] }})(names);
`; Sorry, reading over my comments, I was arguing the wrong thing.

Comment: @cakl: I believe a C++ equivalent would be a capture by reference lambda `[&](params) { body }` ...though I'm very new to C++, so I may be mistaken. Basically the function creates a new lexical scope, and as such, you can refer to  variables in the outer scope. The code in the function always reads the current state of the variable.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by "capturing", but I'm pretty sure that there's no such concept in JavaScript. Nothing special happens when you instantiate a function in some scope, and code in the function has live access to all variables in scope. If multiple functions are created in the same lexical scope, then they all **share** live access to local variables in that scope.

Comment: Tanks @Pointy, with capturing I mean the concept as you can use it with C++ lambdas/objc blocks. At the point of definition of the lambda function, you can pass local or global variables f.e by value/reference/copy to the lambda function. So you can determine the "accessibility" of these passed variables at the point of function definition.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by capturing, but you are destroying the `names` variable which your function has scope access to.

So to answer your question (I think), your function won't keep a local copy of `names`, it will always reference the closest scope.

You *could* achieve it with something like this, which will hold `names` in local scope, even if destroyed in outer scope.

```
var names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three'];

var nameByIndex = (function(names) {
    var _names = names;
    return function (n){
        return _names[n];
    };
})(names);

console.log(nameByIndex(1)); // outputs one
names = undefined; 
console.log(nameByIndex(2)); // outputs two
```